# Class BuyRequestBuilder does not exist after upgrade 2.3.5 to 2.3.7

Tags: magento2, php-7

working on an upgrade from 2.3.5 to 2.3.7 and suddenly got this error when compiling, does anybody know how to fix this?

[image]

Looks like it had to do with me changing to     "minimum-stability": "dev", because of mageplaza smtp asking for that.

I tried to search for information, did a complete new composer install but still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

That class only exists since Magento version 2.4.1, it does not exist in any version of 2.3.
So, you have to change "minimum-stability" to "stable" to make sure everything works as expected.

Comment: I tried that, removed everything again, composer clearcache, composer install etc with

    "minimum-stability": "stable",

but still the same issue :(

Comment: Remove `vendor` and `generated` directories and run `composer install`, then run compile code command again. If it does not work, I think you need to do a `composer update`, if so -> remove `vendor` and `generated` directories and run `composer update`, then run compile code command again.

Comment: Looks like you need to run `composer update`. To install a package that has `minimum-stability` is dev, you can whitelist that package with a stability flag instead of the whole project. Take a look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28240571/how-to-change-minimum-stability-for-just-one-package-in-composer

Comment: Nothing worked, I will just try to  upgrade to 2.4.1 and see what happens :)